# Bringing down/up a network via Python

Tags: python, linux, networking, ip

How do you use python to bring a network down and up after changing IP settings(Using Linux)?  Are any specific permissions required to do so?

Comment: do you know how to do it using linux?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham 'sudo ifdown eth8', I however am not sure of the process in python

Comment: This post talks about how to run shell commands from python. Note that your python script will have to be run with `sudo`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4256107/running-bash-commands-in-python

Comment: use the subprocess module and just run the same command

Comment: I saw a process that did 'subprocess.Popen(["/usr/bin/sudo","/sbin/ifdown","eth8"])'  is this incorrect?

Comment: yes but you don't need the full path I imagine

Comment: @PadraicCunningham would it be necessary to pause in between executions of 'ifdown' and 'ifup'?  As in will 'ifdown' still be running while 'ifup' is called?

Comment: You can use   `proc  = subprocess.Popen(["/usr/bin/sudo","/sbin/ifdown","eth8"])` then `proc.wait()` if you want to be sure.